# Modifying the array's name dynamically

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing Java app.

This is a sample of my code:

```
int [] digitPart_1 ={16,7,9,8,5,6,};
int [] digitPart_2 ={1,77,98,86,5,6,};
int [] digitPart_3 ={166,7,49,84,55,6,};

for(int i = 0; i < mfl.size(); i++){
 new DataProcessing(digitPart_+""+(i + 1));
}
```

In my design now each part (e.g. digitPart_1) shall be passed in, because 0 + 1 = 1, 1 + 1 = 2, i.e. digitPart_1 etc. But that causes compile error. It does not let me modify the name of array I pass in.
The 'mfl' is not important, it shall store number 3. I was just wondering whether I can modify the the name of data-structure I pass in dynamically like you can modify string you pass in to the output stream.

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue?
Cheers

Comment: Can you re-explain what exactly you're trying to do? e.g. what is mfl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot modify varaibles' name dynamically. but you can use an array instead:

```
int[][] digitPart = {{16,7,9,8,5,6}, {1,77,98,86,5,6}, {166,7,49,84,55,6}};

for(int i = 0; i < mfl.size(); i++){
   new DataProcessing(digitPart[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a two-dimensional array since that's pretty much what you're trying to do.  Compiled languages simply do not work like this, although you can look up Java reflection (which, though relevant, is not the proper design tool here.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have dynamic variable names in Java.

Instead, how about using a Map ?

```
Map<Integer, int[]> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();

myMap.put(1 , {16,7,9,8,5,6,} );
myMap.put(2 , {16,7,9,8,5,6,7} );
...

and then 

for ( Integer i : myMap.keySet() ) 
    new DataProcessing(myMap.get(i));
```

Comment: why map if your keys are sequantal integers? an array is better

Comment: Valid point @gefei .. Map was just a suggestion. array of arrays lead to confusion sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you're using fields rather than method local variables.

```
int[] digitPart_1 = { 16, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6, };
int[] digitPart_2 = { 1, 77, 98, 86, 5, 6, };
int[] digitPart_3 = { 166, 7, 49, 84, 55, 6, };

public void foo() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(getClass()
                    .getDeclaredField("digitPart_" + i));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However I'd recommend restructuring your code to use an array of arrays.

```
int[][] digitPart = { { 16, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6, }, { 1, 77, 98, 86, 5, 6, }, { 166, 7, 49, 84, 55, 6, } };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(digitPart[i]);
}
```

Better still I'd use java collections to represent your structure unless you have specific low memory requirements.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> digitPart = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
digitPart.put("digitPart_1", Arrays.asList( 16, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6));
digitPart.put("digitPart_2", Arrays.asList( 1, 77, 98, 86, 5, 6));
digitPart.put("digitPart_3", Arrays.asList(166, 7, 49, 84, 55, 6));

digitPart.get("digitPart_2").get(2); // 98
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is illegal in java. Variable names must me known at compile time.

What you can do instead is create a `Map` where the key is the name of the variable (`digitPart_1`...) and the entry is the array (`{16, 7,...}...`).

In the loop, you can access the arrays through the `Map`.